# Android TouchEvent ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE havesame position the first x Steps

Tags: android, position, box2d, andengine, ontouchlistener

I have a problem using the touchEvents of Android (Andengine).
I noticed the problem by building a Body, which I can rotate by touching it and move the finger.

Thats all working. I touch the Object, the pScenTouchEvent gives me one position (x,y) on ACTION_DOWN. Then I move my finger and the ACTION_MOVE method is called (in my switch). The problem is, that the first 1-6 times, the Position of the ACTION_MOVE block has the same coordinates (x,y) like on ACTION_DOWN.
So the next Position I get has a big distance to the old position. 
Affect: The Body does a big "rotation jump" on the first time.

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Log.d("Position", "down: "+pSceneTouchEvent.getX()+", "+pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
        if (playerIsMoving && touchedFigure == null) {
            System.out.println("reset");
            resetLevel();
        }
        touchedFigure = null;
        break;
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.d("Position", "move: "+pSceneTouchEvent.getX()+", "+pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
        if (!playerIsMoving && touchedFigure != null && touchedFigure instanceof RotatingFigure) {
            ((RotatingFigure) touchedFigure).rotate(touchPositionOld, figureCenterOld, new Vector2(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()));
        } else if (!playerIsMoving && touchedFigure != null && touchedFigure instanceof SlidingFigure) {
            Vector2 newPosition = figureCenterOld;
            newPosition.add(new Vector2(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY()).sub(touchPositionOld));
            ((SlidingFigure) touchedFigure).slide(newPosition);
            touchPositionOld = new Vector2(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is the LogCat output:

```
04-30 12:18:03.476: D/Position(22974): down: 197.5, 287.91666
04-30 12:18:03.546: D/Position(22974): move: 197.5, 287.91666
04-30 12:18:03.746: D/Position(22974): move: 197.5, 287.91666
04-30 12:18:04.136: D/Position(22974): move: 197.5, 287.91666
04-30 12:18:04.526: D/Position(22974): move: 197.5, 287.91666
04-30 12:18:04.696: D/Position(22974): move: 205.92313, 290.86475
04-30 12:18:04.776: D/Position(22974): move: 206.29709, 290.83334
04-30 12:18:04.846: D/Position(22974): move: 206.68404, 290.83334
04-30 12:18:04.926: D/Position(22974): move: 207.1292, 291.29587
04-30 12:18:05.016: D/Position(22974): move: 207.51622, 291.25
04-30 12:18:05.056: D/Position(22974): move: 207.92809, 291.25
04-30 12:18:05.136: D/Position(22974): move: 208.3959, 291.25
04-30 12:18:05.186: D/Position(22974): move: 208.75002, 291.3545
04-30 12:18:05.216: D/Position(22974): move: 208.75002, 291.85513
04-30 12:18:05.316: D/Position(22974): move: 206.34752, 291.66666
```

So what is the problem? In my game the body has to rotate correctly. Has somebody an Idea to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is my Hardware. I tested the same code on an other Smartphone and it worked.